# Conditional expectation of a random variable given an event?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, random-variables, conditional-expectation

**The original question**

> Let $X$, $Y$ be random variables, $\Omega$ be the set of all possible outcomes, and $A$ be an event, such that $X \sim U_{[0,1]}$, $Y \sim U_{[0, 1-x]}$, $A = \{(x,y) \in \Omega : x,y < \frac{1}{2} \}$, and $\Omega = \{(x,y): x,y \geq 0, x+y \leq 1 \}$.
>
> Find $\mathbb{E} (1-x-y\mid A)$.

**My textbook's solution**

They found $f(x,y)$ to be $\frac{1}{1-x}$ and $\mathbb{P}(A)$ to be $\frac{1}{2} \ln(2)$ by double integrating $f(x,y)$.

Then, they did $\mathbb{E} (1-x-y\mid  A) = \frac{1}{\mathbb{P}(A)} \int_{A} (1-x-y) f(x,y)\, dx\, dy$ to find the solution.

**My question**

I'm not sure how they came up with the above integral to find the conditional expectation? I haven't seen this formula before. Any explanation of this would be appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A conditional $\mathbb{E}\big(h(z)\,\big|\,A\big)$ is computed just a like a normal expectation, but we disregard any outcome $z \notin A$.

Now let $f$ be the original density function. If we look *just* at the set of outcomes $A$, $f$ is not a density anymore, because we won't have $\int_A f(z)\,dz = 1$. So we must adjust $f$ by *re-scaling* it to ensure that the integral over $A$ is one. Instead of $f$, we must thus use the density $$
  f_A(z) = \frac{1}{\int_A f(z)\,dz} f(z) = \frac{1}{\mathbb{P}(A)} f(z),
$$
since this guarantees that $\int_A f_A(z)\,dz = \frac{\int_A f(z)\,dz}{\int_A f(z)\,dz} = 1$.

Using the modified density $f_A$, and the usual formula for the expectation $\mathbb{E}\, h(z)$, we then find for the conditional expectation $$
  \mathbb{E}\big(h(z)\,\big|\,A\big) = \int_A h(z)f_A(z)\,dz
 = \frac{1}{\mathbb{P}(A)} \int_A h(z)f(z)\,dz.
$$